# Need some help positioning a cloned, transformed div - (jsfiddle included)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

http://jsfiddle.net/xKuwR/

I want the small clone to sit nicely within the overview div. The goal is to be able to put the overview div anywhere I want, with any positioning (fixed, relative, etc) and have it work.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you're after, but I think using [`-transform-origin`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-3d-transforms/#transform-origin-property) will help:

```
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
```

With `position: fixed` (as you had it): http://jsfiddle.net/xKuwR/5/
With `position: relative`: http://jsfiddle.net/xKuwR/6/

Comment: Great, yes this is what I was looking for - in the end I wanted this: http://jsfiddle.net/xKuwR/7/